# Adding subdirectory to tests in Laravel; connection can't be resolved

Tags: php, laravel-5, namespaces, phpunit

I'm trying to add some structure into my /tests/ directory, at the moment files are structured like this:

- /tests

  - /Models

    - UserTest.php
  - ExampleTest.php
  - TestCase.php

Both UserTest and ExampleTest are extended from TestCase. Running Exampletest works just fine (adds user to database), whereas UserTest fails with the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function connection() on null in [...]\Illuminate\Datab ase\Eloquent\Model.php on line 3340

That means that this functions receives *null* or no argument (model.php:3338-3342):

```
public static function resolveConnection($connection = null)
{
    return static::$resolver->connection($connection);
}
```

I cannot figure out what's different in my two testcases.

**TestCase.php:**

```
<?php
namespace Tests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase as baseTestCase;

class TestCase extends baseTestCase
{
    /**
     * The base URL to use while testing the application.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $baseUrl = 'http://localhost';

    /**
     * Creates the application.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Foundation\Application
     */
    public function createApplication()
    {
        $app = require __DIR__ . '/../bootstrap/app.php';

        $app->make(\Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class)->bootstrap();

        return $app;
    }
}
```

**ExampleTest.php:**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;
use Tests\TestCase;
use App\User;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic functional test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testBasicExample()
    {
        User::create([
            "name" => 'test'
        ]);

        $this->visit('/')
             ->see('Laravel 5');
    }
}
```

**Models/UserTest.php:**

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Models;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Tests\TestCase;
use Faker\Factory;
use App\User;

class UserTest extends TestCase
{
    use DatabaseTransactions;

    protected $user;

    protected $password;

    protected $customPassword;

    protected $testString;
    /**
     * Construct.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    public function __construct()
    {
        $faker = Factory::create();

        $this->password = $faker->password;
        $this->customPassword = $faker->password;

        $this->user = User::create([
            "name" => $faker->name,
            "email" => $faker->email,
            "password" => Hash::shouldReceive($this->password),
        ]);

    }

    public function testExample()
    {
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

Anyone has an idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is happening because as you are extending "TestCase" from Models/UserTest and it is looking "TestCase" inside your Models folder, try giving a full path to that class.

Something like:

```
class UserTest extends {yourNameSpace(ifAny)}\TestCase
```